# How to create packages for different configurations of the same product in PackageScript?

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker

we call Mac PackageMaker from an Ant script, to build our product installation package.
I would like to pass a parameter 'productConfiguration', that will direct the package to include or exclude certain components, e.g. in order to create a smaller Trial version package.

What is the correct way to achieve that? 
Notes:

1. In Windows we use InstallShield's Features, Conditions, Release Flags, Configuration Flags. 
   Are there similar concepts in PackageMaker?)
2. Where is the documentation of pkmkdoc spec 1.12?
3. The only way I can think of, is to generate [some of] the xml files inside the install.pmdoc smart folder, using templates. But it looks very inelegant to me.

Answer (score 0):

Packagemaker doesn't contain a lot of sophisticated features for things like this. I would suggest tweaking the ant script by creating a separate build target that builds the trial installer. This target can customize both the files included and the PackageMaker parameters.